# Android: Repository-Pattern and Pagination

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Recently, I've read about how important it is to have a Single-Source-Of-Truth (SSOT) when designing an app´s back-end (repository, not server-side-back-end). https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

By developing a news-feed app (using the awesome https://newsapi.org/) I am trying to learn more about app architecture. However, I am unsure of how to implement paging. By the way,.: I am using MVVM for my presentation layer. The View subscribes to the ViewModel´s LiveData. The ViewModel subscribes to RxJava streams.

I came up with the following approach:

```
interface NewsFeedRepository {
        fun getNewsFeed(): Observable<List<Article>>
        fun refreshFeed(): Completable
        fun loadMore(): Completable
}
```

The ViewModel subscribes to the `getNewsFeed()` Observable which emits data every time the underlying data in the database (SSOT) changes. However, my question is regarding the `loadMore()` method.
This method attempts to load more articles from the API and on success insert them into the local database. This causes `getNewsFeed()` to emit the new feed data.

My questions:

**1.** Should the repository be responsible for syncing API and local database data? Or should the repository use some "low-level" API that manages syncing network/local data?

**2.** The method `loadMore` returns a `Completable` which might seem weird/misleading. Are there better ways to indicate paging in the repository interface?

**3.** Paging means storing a current page count and use it when requesting data from the API. Where should the current page count be stored? In the repository? Or in some "lower-level" component that is being used by the repository?

```
interface SearchArticleRepository {
    fun searchArticles(sources: List<NewsSource>? = null, query: String? = null): Flowable<List<Article>>
    fun moreArticles(): Completable  
}
```

This repository is used to search articles. The method `moreArticles()` attempts to load more articles from the API depending on the last call to `searchArticles(...)`. For example: The ViewModel calls `repo.searchArticles(q = "bitcoin")`. A call to `repo.moreArticles()` attempts to load more articles that contain the query string `"bitcoin"` from the API and sync with the local database.

Again my questions:

**1.** Is it OK to store information about the last request (`searchArticles(request)` in the repository? I could also think of passing the request parameters in `moreArticles()` too, e.g. `moreArticles(sources: List<NewsSource>? = null, query: String? = null)`. This way the repository doesn't have to store information about the last request.

**2.** Again, returning a `Completable` in `moreArticles()` might seem weird. Is this OK, or are there better ways?

Comment: use [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) support lib

Comment: @pskink But I want to separate business logic from view. I've read a tutorial about the paging lib but I can't see how to fully seperate backend from view. Also how could the paging lib work with MVI (uni-directional  dataflow)?

Comment: see `PagedListAdapter` and `LivePagedListBuilder`

Comment: @Elias did you ever come up with a good solution for this?